# clang++ fails but g++ succeeds on using a cast to const-unrelated-type operator in an assignment

Tags: c++11, g++, language-lawyer, clang++, conversion-operator

Here's a short example that reproduces this [“no viable conversion” with lemon for clang but valid for g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632584/no-viable-conversion-with-lemon-for-clang-but-valid-for-g) difference in compiler behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { 
    int i; 
};

#ifndef UNSCREW_CLANG
using cast_type = const A;
#else 
using cast_type = A;
#endif

struct B {
    operator cast_type () const {
        return A{i};
    }
    int i;
}; 

int main () { 
    A a{0};
    B b{1};

#ifndef CLANG_WORKAROUND
    a = b;
#else    
    a = b.operator cast_type ();
#endif    

    std::cout << a.i << std::endl;    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**[live](http://goo.gl/8rlm1B) at godbolt's**

g++ (4.9, 5.2) compiles that silently; whereas clang++ (3.5, 3.7) compiles it

if

```
using cast_type = A;
```

or

```
using cast_type = const A;
// [...] 
a = b.operator cast_type ();
```

are used, 
**but not** with the defaulted

```
using cast_type = const A;
// [...] 
a = b;
```

In that case clang++ (3.5) blames `a = b`:

```
testling.c++:25:9: error: no viable conversion from 'B' to 'A'
    a = b;
        ^
testling.c++:3:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) 
not viable:
      no known conversion from 'B' to 'const A &' for 1st argument
struct A { 
       ^
testling.c++:3:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) 
not viable:
      no known conversion from 'B' to 'A &&' for 1st argument
struct A { 
       ^
testling.c++:14:5: note: candidate function
    operator cast_type () const {
    ^
testling.c++:3:8: note: passing argument to parameter here
struct A {
```

**With reference to the 2011¹ standard: Is clang++ right about rejecting the defaulted code or is g++ right about accepting it?**

**Nota bene**: This is **not** a question about whether that `const` qualifier on the `cast_type` makes sense. This is about which compiler works standard-compliant **and only about that**.

¹ 2014 should not make a difference here.

**EDIT:**

*Please refrain from re-tagging this with the generic c++ tag.
I'd first like to know which behavior complies to the 2011 standard, and keep the committees' dedication `not to break existing (< 2011) code` out of ansatz for now.*

Comment: I tried to reproduce too : http://goo.gl/dQ7EFa

Comment: With your before c++11 compatible code : http://goo.gl/HHeIvg , if you remove compiler options (`-std=c++11`), clang 3.7 succeeds...

Comment: @Isammoc: Yup, but g++ fails with each and every right, because the `using` directives are a 2011 extension. clang++, btw blames it as such, but just with a warning.  Anyway I'd like  that to be analyzed on the grounds of the 2011 standard (2014 should not make a difference here).

Comment: @decltype_auto Why do you think 2014 shouldn't make a different here?  (is it just a thought, or do you have some reason?)

Comment: @Yakk: Because if there was a difference, regression tests would almost certainly have barked.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour. I dislike that tag edit; I chose the tags on purpose.

Comment: @decltype_auto I understand, all the discussions I have read on meta say include the generic tag like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265844/1708801). Although I have seen this a lot more often maybe we need a meta discussion for this, let me see if I can find a C++ version of this question on meta.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: is that a standing rule on SO? You own proposed answer is a factual rationale for why not tagging it general c++.

Comment: @decltype_auto I would not call it a rule, it is a consensus of the community. See this [question specific to C++](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274921/1708801). You can leave out the generic C++ tag but it is almost for sure a high rep user will add it.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: "I would not call it a rule" . Thus it is no rule. So what was wrong about my question's tagging **according the rules of SO** that demanded you, by your edit, marking my question as wrongfully tagged , please?

Comment: @decltype_auto I made the edit in good faith based on the communities norms, in general that is how the community works. If you feel strongly you should revert the change. Keep in mind on future question you ask, this will likely happen again since this is the norm and most high rep users will add the C++ tag to questions that only have version specific tags in it.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: "high rep" does not constitute a rationale for applying a different ruleset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it looks like this is covered by this clang bug report [rvalue overload hides the const lvalue one?](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16682)  which has the following example:

```
struct A{};
struct B{operator const A()const;};
void f(A const&);
#ifdef ERR
void f(A&&);
#endif
int main(){
  B a;
  f(a);
}
```

which fails with the same error as the OP's code. Richard Smith toward the end says:

> Update: we're correct to choose 'f(A&&)', but we're wrong to reject
>   the initialization of the parameter. Further reduced:
>
> ```
>   struct A {};
>   struct B { operator const A(); } b;
>   A &&a = b;
> ```
>
> Here, [dcl.init.ref]p5 bullet 2 bullet 1 bullet 2 does not apply,
>   because [over.match.ref]p1 finds no candidate conversion functions,
>   because "A" is not reference-compatible with "const A". So we fall
>   into [dcl.init.ref]p5 bullet 2 bullet 2, and copy-initialize a
>   temporary of type A from 'b', and bind the reference to that. I'm not
>   sure where in that process we go wrong.

but then comes back with another comment due to a [defect report 1604](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1604):

> DR1604 changed the rules so that
>
> ```
>  A &&a = b;
> ```
>
> is now ill-formed. So we're now correct to reject the initialization.
>   But this is still a terrible answer; I've prodded CWG again. We should
>   probably discard f(A&&) during overload resolution.

So it seems like clang is technically doing the right thing based on the standard language today but it may change since there seems to be disagreement at least from the clang team that this is the correct outcome. So presumably this will result in a defect report and we will have to wait till it is resolved before we can come to a final conclusion.

**Update**

Looks like [defect report 2077](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2077) was filed based on this issue.

Comment: Good work, but does a statement  like "we should **probably** discard [sth]" really make sense in a discussion about standard-defined behavior?  It's "either-or" not "probably" and the truth values of those 'either-or' alternatives should be given by the standard, or not?

Comment: @decltype_auto well Richard Smith is on the committee and so he believes if I understand correctly there is defect and the current resolution should be fixed. That is of course an opinion but an authoritative one and if the rest of the committee agrees with him then it will become a fact :-)

Comment: But argumenta ad  verecundiam aside, either  the standard is not unambiguous in that regard, or clang's behavior  either right or wrong in that regard, or do you disagree?

Comment: @decltype_auto it is not always that clean cut we can see fro this [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29683948/1708801) gcc is not conformant but believes the defect will resolve in their favor and so leaves a change in place. We can find compromises like this all the time and they often fall under quality of implementation.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced that this should constitute the conclusion we draw here, but if you add that to your answer I'll accept it. And least we know, thanks to your good work, that it is an known issue and thus doesn't require filing a bug report ourself. Thank you!